# Request based routing by header parameter values in Rest DSL in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I want to route the messages to different routes based on the data coming in header parameters.

```
rest()  
    .tag("API")
    .id("eventRest")
    .post("/data").description("Post a new settlement data record")
    .consumes("application/json")
    .param().type(RestParamType.header).name("channelID").endParam().to("direct:customRoute")
```

Here If I've the different param then this one should bypass and continue the rest of the flow in my program.

Comment: There is the content-based router. You can use that.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti , to use content based routing, Rest DSL specifications doesn't support this.

Comment: what? Off course it does. Just send the message to a second route which handles the actual routing logic.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti, In that way you mentioned we can do but my requirement is to do two type(.type) bindings based on the header value parameter. As you can see the code snippet above, I can't check the param values using .param() and bind accordingly using .type(). If I want to do then I need to route() and then do the .choice() or content based routing. But I want to know for any other way of pojo binding before route() as .type() cannot be used after  choice() in route(),